# android webview setdefaultfontsize(int size), what is the size unit?

Tags: android, webview, font-size

android webview

```
webview.setdefaultfontsize(int size);
```

what is the size unit?

```
webview.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(20);
```

Is it `20pt` or `20dp` or other uinit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

unit for font is sp

### sp

Scale-independent Pixels - this is like the dp unit, but it is also scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you use this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for both the screen density and user's preference.

for more information about sp,dp,pixels please refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

Comment: Could you please link a documentation?

Comment: There's no where to find in your link that it is the default unit used by the WebView